# How to set the views exposed filters default value programmatically?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view which has a term reference exposed filter.

I want to set the default values of this exposed filter programmatically based on a certain condition.

I have tried the following code but the values are not selected in the filter.

```
function example_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'events') {
    $tids = array(5, 6);
    foreach (tids as $tid) {
      $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['field_category']->value[$tid] = $tid;
    }
  }
}
```

AND

```
function example_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
      if ($view->name == 'events') {
        $tids = array(5, 6);
        foreach (tids as $tid) {
          $view->display[$view->current_display]->display_options['filters']['field_category']->value[$tid] = $tid;
        }
      }
    }
```

I also tried with `form_alter`, in form alter the values gets selected in the filter but then it does not display correct results after removing/applying again the filter.

Answer (score 1):

```
function example_views_pre_build(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
        $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['field_country_tid']->value = array(55, 91);
    }
}
```

This code worked for me. Check your views module version as well. I am using Views 7.x-3.14.

Comment: mine is also 7.x-3.14 version :(

Comment: have you tried with BEF checkboxes? I'm using BEF checkboxes

Comment: Forgot to mention one more thing - I have tested this with multi-value select field, not checkbox.

Comment: checkboxes do behave similar to a select element, @Ahmad the problem with your code is that views expect filters to be a numeric indexed array, using $tid as key will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for multiple value filter (D7):

```
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    $view->filter['FIELD_NAME']->value = array('nouveau', 'pending', 'complete', 'waitlist', 'held', 'canceled');
  }
}
```